# How to create multiple iterations

Tags: python

I wanna know how do I create an iteration which would iterate several or more than one parameters with different ranges
For example I wanna instantiate several object with iterations that all have different ranges.
Like there is a triangle function which takes three parameters, how do I use iterations to give one parameter one value from a range e.g. 50 to 100 and another parameter a different one altogether.

I know how to instantiate it over one parameter by:

```
for i in range(100):
```

But what do I do to instantiate it if it requires more than one parameter for a function.

Comment: Do you mean these triangle functions http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleFunction.html?  What kind of arguments does your function take?

Comment: No sorry for the confusion, it's just a function that determines whether given three values can make a triangle or not

Comment: takes x,y,z for each side of a triangle

Comment: Why do you need a loop?  That's just computing Pythagoras no?  Actually, the rule is `(a + b) > c` I think.  So `def is_tri(a, b, c): return (a + b) > c`

Comment: I wanted to instantiate a large number of values to see how efficient the algorithm is, it just checks whether the sum of two sides apart from the largest is greater than the largest side, Pythagoras only applies on right angled triangles so

Comment: The you can use something like `itertools.product` to make tuples of varying values.  Iterate that iteraor and pass values into the function.

Comment: Thanks, um a correction, the function u gave wouldn't work because assume u have values 500,300,100, here a + b is greater than c but it isn't a triangle because b + c is not greater than a, so taking out the largest first and comparing it makes it easier

Comment: Noted.  The answer i posted sorts the arguments before comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will want to use *nested* for loops.  For example for your three parameter function:

```
# these are just example ranges, replace with what's meaningful for your problem
range_for_parameter_0 = range(100)
range_for_parameter_1 = range(150)
range_for_parameter_2 = range(75)

# start a nested for loop
for i in range_for_parameter_0:
    for j in range_for_parameter_1:
        for k in range_for_parameter_2:
            # you can print something out to see exactly what's happening
            # feel free to comment out the print statement
            print('Calling triangle_function with parameters {},{},{}'.format(i,j,k))

            # evaluate your triangle_function which takes 3 parameters
            triangle_function(i,j,k)
```

Comment: seems pretty nice, where did u get this from? a book or something for ref cause I've been searching a lot of them which would give advanced techniques but can't find any good ones

Comment: Hi Afzal, a good source of information when you're getting started is https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ .  The page that discusses for loops is https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements .  If you look at 4.4, they have an example that uses nested for loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can try iterating over a Cartesian [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

**Given**

```
import itertools as it


def is_tri(a, b, c):
    """Return True if the sides make a triangle."""
    a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])
    return (a + b) > c

ranges = range(1, 2), range(1, 3), range(1, 5)
```

**Code**

```
[sides for sides in it.product(*ranges) if is_tri(*sides)]
# [(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2)]
```

---

**Details**

If you are unfamiliar with list comprehensions, the latter is equivalent to the following code:

```
results = []
for x, y, z in it.product(*ranges):
    if is_tri(x, y, z):
        results.append((x, y, z))

results
# [(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2)]
```

Per your comment, `is_tri()` pre-sorts arguments, so you interchange them:

```
assert is_tri(13, 12, 5) == True 
assert is_tri(12, 5, 13) == True
assert is_tri(5, 13, 12) == True
```

If your ranges are the same, you can simplify the input with the `repeat` parameter, e.g. `it.product(range(1, 101), repeat=3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need three iterations.

```
for i in range(x):
    ...

for j in range(y):
    ...

for k in range(z):
    ...
```

See `range()` definition [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Comment: yes but I can't instantiate with giving only one parameter at a time

Comment: `range(start, stop[, step])` function can only take one `stop` parameter, so you either go with a nested loop in a nested loop (really bad performance-wise) or you restructure your algorithm logic altogether and refactor your code accordingly.